# Sidekiq not connecting to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, sidekiq

I am having issues converting from Resque to Sidekiq. I'm not getting any errors though a `perform_async(ids)` doesn't add anything to Redis. I can add keys directly to the Redis server via the `Redis.current.append("test", "key")`
Also my Sidekiq worker connects to the Redis server, though I get an empty array when I ask for `Sidekiq::Client.registered_workers` The web UI shows only the skeleton with no information other than the Redis info. I don't know if this matters but `Sidekiq.redis { |conn| conn.info }` returns information that is all correct with my local Redis server. Though `Sidekiq.server?` returns a nil value.

**Update:** When I perform a `perform_async(args)` it returns a string.

Comment: Obvious questions: You're running the latest Sidekiq (2.14.1) and have Redis 2.4 or higher installed? And you're using at least Ruby 1.9.3?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Sidekiq configuration isn't using the same redis config for the client and server components of Sidekiq.

The client executes within your Rails app server, while the server is a stand-alone separate process where work is performed.  If they both aren't using the same redis queue via the redis configuration, work will not be processed.

Here is an example `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` config block using the same redis for both components:

```
redis = { url: (ENV['REDIS_URL'] || 'redis://127.0.0.1'), namespace: 'sidekiq' }

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = redis
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = redis
end
```

My guess is that you have a different namespace or configuration between your client and server config.

Comment: Sorry, I already have a `sidekiq.rb` that configures the server and client to the same namespace and Redis address.

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting the same issue.

Turns out I had `rspec-sidekiq` configured in my `Gemfile`'s `development` group and [rspec-sidekiq](https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq) apparently stubs the async calls for testing.

The solution was amending my `Gemfile` as such:

```
gem 'rspec-sidekiq', group: :test, require: false
```

Finally, I added `require 'rspec-sidekiq'` in my `spec_helper.rb`.